# Drupal 8 assign module template to a page

Tags: templates, module, drupal-8

I am new in drupal and i am creating a module to allow customers to customize card using fabric js. I created a module and inside it i have created a template file inside my_module > templates > page--my_module.html.twig. The issue is that i am not able to view the content of the template on a page.

Here is the code of my my_module.module file

```
    <?php

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */
function my_module_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  switch ($route_name) {
    case 'help.page.my_module':
      return t('
        <h2>Lorem ipsum generator for Drupal.</h2>
        <h3>Instructions</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... <strong>Just kidding!</strong></p>
        <p>Unpack in the <em>modules</em> folder (currently in the root of your Drupal 8 installation) and enable in <strong>/admin/modules</strong>.</p>
        <p>Then, visit <strong>/admin/config/development/loremipsum</strong> and enter your own set of phrases to build random-generated text (or go with the default Lorem ipsum).</p>
        <p>Last, visit <strong>www.example.com/loremipsum/generate/P/S</strong> where:</p>
        <ul>
          <li><em>P</em> is the number of <em>paragraphs</em></li>
          <li><em>S</em> is the maximum number of <em>sentences</em></li>
        </ul>
        <p>There is also a generator block in which you can choose how many paragraphs and
phrases and it\'ll do the rest.</p>
        <p>If you need, there\'s also a specific <em>generate lorem ipsum</em> permission.</p>
        <h3>Attention</h3>
        <p>Most bugs have been ironed out, holes covered, features added. But this module is a work in progress. Please report bugs and suggestions, ok?</p>
      ');
  }
}

/**
* Implements hook_theme() to add the template definition.
**/
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_module_template' => array(
        'template' => 'page--my_module',
      'variables' => array('test_var' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is the code of the controller MyModuleController.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\card_designer\Controller\FirstController.
 */

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase {
  public function content() {
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'card_designer_template',
      '#test_var' => $this->t('Test Value'),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code of my_module.routing.yml

```
  my_module.content:
  path: '/card-design'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleController::content'
    _title: 'Hello world'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'**strong text**
```

And here is the page--my_module.html.twig file

```
<p> This is the lotus template with a value of {{ test_var }} </p>
```

Now don't know how to assign this my custom template to a page so that i can check the output of the template on a the website.

Can anyone tell me where i am wrong and how i can see the output on a page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. In "my_module.routing.yml" fix `_permission: 'access content'**strong text**`to `_permission: 'access content'`. I am not sure where did you get `**strong text**` but it should not be here.
2. Rename "page--my_module.html.twig" to "page--my-module.html.twig". Twig template names should not have underscores.
3. In "MyModuleController.php" change `'#theme' => 'card_designer_template',` to `'#theme' => 'page__my_module',` because machine name of template must match all others theme naming usages. Please note that `page__my_module` is using underscores when used in PHP, but when used as name of twig template file, underscores are converted to hyphens => `page--my-module.html.twig`.
4. In "my_module.module" Change

```
'my_module_template' => array(
        'template' => 'page--my_module',
      'variables' => array('test_var' => NULL),
    ),
```

to

```
'page__my_module' => array(
  'variables' => array('test_var' => NULL),
),
```

because template machine name must be parent key and variables should be child key. Also "template" key can be removed, because after fix it is defined in parent key as already said.

5. I am not sure if you have "my_module.info.yml" but is should be something like:

```
name: my_module
type: module
description: 'My custom module'
package: 'Custom'
core: 8.x
```

6. I am not sure about your structure but it should be like this:

[image]

I hope I did not missed anything :) I fixed and tested your code, so if it does not work, let me know and I will fix my answer.